# Как получить координаты маркера

Tags: google-maps-api, карты

Как получить координаты маркера в переменную "coordinates" для последующей отправки с помощью ajax?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

        if (marker != undefined) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        }

        latlng = event.latLng;
        var coordinates = latlng;
        $("body").on("click", "#button_save_coordinates", function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_coordinates.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {"coordinates" : coordinates},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
    });
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            clickable: true,
            map: map,
            title: 'title',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            visible: true
        });
      });
```

Данный код не хочет отправлять:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить coordinates:
Вместо:

```
var coordinates = latlng;
```

Заменить на:

```
var lat = latlng.lat();
var lng = latlng.lng();
var coordinates = lat+", "+lng;
```